Can you use a comparison operator and an arithmetic operator in the same AVERAGEIFS formula?
I want to take the average of a set of numbers in one column (which we'll call column X) meeting a few different conditions: in one column (column A), there has to be matching text of the same contents of A2; in another column (B), there has to be matching text of the contents of B2; in another column (C), the cell must be equal to the number 9 (which represents the year I'm referencing; but if there are no cells meeting those two conditions, it needs to then take the average of column X based off of all rows in column D that are within 5% of the number in cell D2--as well as all rows in column B matching the contents of cell B2, and all rows in column C equaling the number 9. This would be repeated in tens of thousands of rows.
To make the example very easy, I've created a different worksheet with a very simplified example (just one column of number and then one other number in a different cell for the reference). Cells A1:A9 contain a set of numbers: 1, 5, 16, 4, 3, 9, 10, 7, 5. The average of these numbers is 6.666667. Another cell, C7, contains the number 2. So I want to take the average of the cells that are greater than 50% of cell C7: in other words, the average of this set of numbers greater than 1, which would mean the average of this set of number without cell A1 because 1 is not greater than 1. That number would be 7.375.
How do I get there with a formula? Here's what I tried:
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A9, ">(c7*0.5)", A1:A9)
But it gave me a #DIV/0. Please see the attached image below.
Let me know if you have a solution! Thanks. :)


=AVERAGEIF(A1:A9, ">" &(c7*0.5), A1:A9)  the math and cell reference should be outside the quotes.
